# Progress 4GL Include de arquivos com variável no path

Tags: progress-4gl

Olá

No Progress 4GL é possível incluir arquivos com a diretiva:

```
{program.i} //Includes program.i in the current program
```

Porém, não consegui montar um diretório enviado por variável ou similar:

```
{{pasta}/program.i} //Includes program.i in the current program
```

É possível fazer alguma constante ou variável dos includes no Progress?

Comment: Eu acredito que não de para fazer isso pois o arquivo é incluído em tempo de compilação e não em tempo de execução. Documentação [Include file reference](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref/%7B-%7D-include-file-reference.html)

Comment: Acredito que dessa forma de fato não há, mas estou vendo alguma variável de ambiente como o PROPATH que pudesse ser alterado de acordo com dependendo do ambiente. Vou analisar outras opções, obrigado.